# base64 to file in java6 with data longer than 65000

Tags: file, base64, java-6

I've Base64 code that i need to open it as file , i used  DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary which is working fine with data less than 65000 , but the issue that i receive codes which is longer than that how can i manage this in JAVA6 ???
Below is the Code i'm using , which is working fine with code less than 65000

```
CREATE OR REPLACE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "BlobHandler" AS
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class BlobHandler
{
  public static void ExportBlob(String CONTFILE, BLOB CONTBLOB) throws Exception
  {
  try
  {
    File file = new File("/u01/oracle/jam_export/contract1");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);  
    //Decoding
    byte[] decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("JVBERi0xLjcNCiW1"); 
    System.out.println("PDF File Saved");
    fos.write(decoded); 
    fos.flush();
    fos.close(); 
    }
    catch  (Exception e) 
    {
     System.out.println(e); 
    }
  }
 };
```

Note DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("JVBERi0xLjcNCiW1");  is a part of the BASE64 code for the post character limitation

Comment: is there something not clear in my question or i should post it with other tags so i can get a response ??